# How to fix an error while uploading flutter app in in AppStore?

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, app-store

Last week I have been trying to publish my app Flutter app in App Store.

What do I have

1. app is compilable and works as expected on my iPhone and in emulator
2. apple dev account - OK
3. all done with certificates and apple dev page content (app screenshots and description added)
4. Archive was created in x-code without any errors
5. The last step to upload my app from x-code to apple dev page finished with an errors. Screenshot is attached
   [image]

I have found some suggestions to remove
Pods_Runner.framework from project but i am not sure it will help

[image]

[image]

I do not understand what should I do to make it work. If anyone faced with this issue before please leave comment

Answer (score 1):

So it was true!  Pods_Runner.framework should be deleted from "Frameworks, Libraries^ and Embedded Content".

Have no idea how it get there, but on official flutter docs about how to upload iOS app there is a screenshot of this configuration screen and there is not
Pods_Runner.framework file on it.

I hope this will help someone who want to publish to Appstore!